# SQL Server : how to move NOT NULL column(with its data) to another table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alter

I have many to many relation, I want to change it to one to many relation.

- Table A which has two FKs will be dropped.
- one of the Fks in table A will be moved to table B.
- FKs is not nullable.

My approach so far is like this:

1. Add **nullable** column(FK) to table B as.
2. insert data into table B from Table A.
3. Alter column to be **NOT NULL**.

Now my question:

- Can I achieve that without step 1?
- Is there any another "better" approach?

Comment: No, there is no "magic" way to "move" a column with its data to another table in single step. What you're doing is the best I can think of.

Comment: I know this isn't really a great question to ask in general, but why do you want to do this? Is it just a general curiosity, or is there some specific reason you're looking to get around that three-step process? It sounds like what you're trying to do is generally a one-time SSMS fix and not something that would be of concern performance-wise or anything. Curiosity is valid, don't get me wrong, I'm just wondering whether there's something else playing into this question that we might be able to help make clearer or easier.

Answer (score 0):

I see marc_s has already mentioned this in a comment, but for people viewing this question in the future I'll say it again here.

There is no way to do this in the current version of SQL Server. Even if there were a shortcut, it would likely be nothing more than "syntactic sugar," as they say, to do exactly what you're talking about.